# How to define and use database relationships in dexie js?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

Is it possible to create a relationship in `indexDB` using `Dexie js`

If possible how to define and use them ?

*i have tried looking through the `Dexie js` documentation they haven't mentioned database relationship anywhere*

[Dexie documention](https://dexie.org/docs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is package [dexie-relationships](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie-relationships). I've tried it but finally remove. Cuz:

1. `indexedDb` does not have real relationships like I used to in MySQL. This library is just sugar over `dexie`.
2. I faced problem with drop table, cuz reltionships library does not accepts `null` in table definition (tries to `null.split()` it).
3. Instead of that library I use simple repositories (classes or functions) to fetch all required data with short syntax. And so you don't need relationships library cuz all relations are hidden in repositories and you don't need to use relations directly.
4. `Dexie` v3.0 is now in `beta.1` stage and I don't know whether compatible with `dexie-relationships` or would ever.

PS: too late, but I think it should be published. It would save me a lot of time if I read this few month before.

Comment: maybe they'll continue supporting it seems as `David Fahlander` the creator of Dexie js is one of the collaborator